# GNU parallel loses pv progress output

Tags: pipe, gnu-parallel

It seems if I use GNU Parallel to wrap a command that uses the `pv` (pipe viewer) command, it loses the command's progress output.

For example, if I run the following `pv` command, which shows the progress of my gzip:

```
› dd if=/dev/urandom bs=256m count=1 | (pv --progress -s 256m --bytes | gzip > /dev/null)
 208MiB [=============================>                                                    ] 32%
```

... it works fine. However, if I wrap the same command with GNU parallel:

```
parallel 'dd if=/dev/urandom bs={} count=1 | (pv --progress -s {} --bytes | gzip > /dev/null)' ::: 256m
```

... I no longer see the in progress gzip progress, but only the final script output in the end.

Question: Not sure if it's my `pv` or `parallel` being the problem, but is there a way to show individual command (Unix pipeline) progress (not job progress which `parallel --progress` gives) if I am using `pv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU Parallel saves output to temporary files and when the job is done, it prints these. So it is basically running this for every command:

```
(cmd; cmd) > tmp.out 2> tmp.err
cat tmp.out
cat tmp.err >&2
```

This is the reason you do not see any output.

You *can* ask GNU Parallel to not use temporary files, but only buffer full lines with `--line-buffer`. That does not work here, because `pv` really wants a tty.

Luckily you can also ask GNU Parallel to connect the tty with `--tty`. GNU Parallel assumes that when you connect a tty that you only want a single job to be running (i.e. `--jobs 1`), but you can override this:

```
parallel -j2 --tty 'dd  if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count={} | (pv --progress -s {} --bytes | gzip > /dev/null)' ::: 20M 10M
```